# Unauthorized confirmation code to ubuntu one

Tags: ubuntu-one

I just signed up for an ubuntu one account and got a confirmation link via email. Instead of checking my email in the browser, I did so on my phone, which was clearly a mistake because after logging in with the provided link, I got the following error:

> Unauthorized confirmation code. You are not authorized to use this confirmation code. If this URL was sent to you by email, please make sure you open it in the same browser where you requested it.

I re-entered the link, now in the same browser I had used to sign up. But the same error emerged. I checked the FAQs at help.ubuntu.com but couldn't find an answer.

How can I now confirm my ubuntu one account?

Comment: Does the link possibly break up into multiple lines in your mail? The fact that you tried it on your phone first shouldn't matter though.

Comment: Hi @Jos, indeed it does. But if I copy-paste it into the search field of my browser, it looks intact and leads to the same error page.